# Jackson Streaming API does not detect out of context writing

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using Jackson 2.5.1 (com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator) to write JSON document to an output stream. It looks like the API allow us to write wrong JSON to the stream? I thought if we try to write elements in wrong context, it is supposed to throw JsonGenerationException or IOException. Here is the code snippet :

```
try {
  JsonFactory jfactory = new JsonFactory();
  ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  JsonGenerator jsonGenerator = jfactory.createJsonGenerator(b, JsonEncoding.UTF8);
  jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
  jsonGenerator.writeStringField("str1", "blahblah");
  jsonGenerator.writeNumber(1234);
  jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
  jsonGenerator.close();
  System.out.println(b.toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The output is : {"str1":"blahblah":1234} and it is not a valid JSON. Is this expected behavior or I am missing something? I thought the API itself tracks if the objects are written in correct context. Does it need to be enforced by the application itself? It is not clear from the documentation :
http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonGenerator.html

Comment: After digging deeper, it looks like the out of context writing exception was part of API a while ago (1.8.5)...but not in the latest version (2.5.1 or newer). I suspect it has something to do with performance considerations.